# Error code: too few arguments to function

Tags: c

My first big "program" that I'm trying to make and I keep getting an error for the packages (ie. pkgA(), pkgB(), pkgC() ). I have never used a call function before and tried to find a few solutions with a * symbol or the & but I didn't quite figure out where or why you would use either of those when calling a function? Maybe I misinterpreted it when reading over the post. (please note this is nowhere near finished and I do have to change quite a number of things, any help or information regarding format in general is greatly appreciated)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int inputHours()
{
int hours;
char hours_verify;

do
{
    do
    {
    printf("Number of hours from 0 to 720: ");
    scanf(" %i", &hours);
    }while(hours<0||hours>720);
    
    printf("%i hours, correct?\n", hours);
    printf("Y/N\n");
    scanf(" %c", &hours_verify);
    
}while(toupper((unsigned char)hours_verify) != 'Y');

printf("%i hours of internet were used.\n", hours);

return (hours);
}

int pkgA(int hours)
{
int pkgprice= 15; //The package price under 50 hours
int extra_price= 2; //Price per hour over 50 hours

if(hours<=50) //Price under 50 hours
    {
    printf("The total price is:$%i", pkgprice);
    }
else if(hours<=720) //Calculate anything over 50 hours
    {
    int extra_hours=hours - 50;

    float total_price=extra_hours * extra_price + pkgprice;
    printf("The total price is:$%.2f", total_price);
    }

return 0;

}

int pkgB(int hours)
{
int pkgprice= 20; //The package price under 100 hours
float extra_price= 1.5; //Price per hour over 100 hours

if(hours<=100) //Price under 100 hours
    {
    printf("The total price is:%i", pkgprice);
    }
else if(100<hours<720) //Calculate anything over 100 hours
    {
    int extra_hours=hours - 100;
    printf("%i\n", extra_hours);

    float total_price=extra_hours * extra_price + pkgprice;
    printf("The total price is:$%.2f", total_price);
    }
return 0;
}

int pkgC(int hours)
{
int pkgprice= 25; //The package price under 150 hours
int extra_price= 1; //Price per hour over 150 hours

scanf("%i", &hours);
printf("%i\n", hours);

if(hours<=150) //Price under 150 hours
    {
    printf("The total price is:%i", pkgprice);
    }
else if(150<hours<720) //Calculate anything over 150 hours
    {
    int extra_hours=hours - 150;
    printf("%i\n", extra_hours);

    float total_price=extra_hours * extra_price + pkgprice;
    printf("The total price is:$%.2f", total_price);
    }
return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
char package_choice;
char package_verify;

do
{
    printf("Which package would you like to select? A, B, or C ");
    scanf(" %c", &package_choice);

    printf("You chose %c, correct?\n", package_choice);
    printf("Y/N\n");

    scanf(" %c", &package_verify);
}while(toupper((unsigned char)package_verify) != 'Y');

printf("You chose package %c.\n", package_choice);

inputHours;
int hours=inputHours();

switch(package_choice)
{
    case 'A':
    pkgA();
    break;
    
    case 'B':
    pkgB();
    break;
    
    case 'C':
    pkgC();
    break;
}
}
```

My output code is:

```
main.c:123:9: error: too few arguments to function ‘pkgA’
  123 |         pkgA();
      |         ^~~~
main.c:35:5: note: declared here
   35 | int pkgA(int hours)
      |     ^~~~
main.c:127:9: error: too few arguments to function ‘pkgB’
  127 |         pkgB();
      |         ^~~~
main.c:56:5: note: declared here
   56 | int pkgB(int hours)
      |     ^~~~
main.c:131:9: error: too few arguments to function ‘pkgC’
  131 |         pkgC();
      |         ^~~~
main.c:76:5: note: declared here
   76 | int pkgC(int hours)
      |     ^~~~
```

I have tried using the `&` or the `*` that I found (both caused more problems than solving any), I tried to change up how it was in the parentheses (for example: `int pkgA(int inputHours)` or int `pkgA(int &inputHours)`. I think there might be a disconnect between the function name and the integer name? I'm not quite sure. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.  Those functions take an argument but you're not passing any.

Comment: I guess I'm confused then, if I called the function forward before hand in main(void) to add the value it needs to pass, why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Within the `switch()` block, change, for example, `pkgA();` to `pkgA( hours );`... No extra `int` should appear anywhere. Do this for all three function calls...

Comment: `pkgA` is defined as a function that receives a single integer parameter named `hours`. It uses this value to carry out whatever task you designed the function to do. Now, you are trying to call it as `pkgA()` -- _i.e_ supplying _no value_ for that parameter. Ask yourself what that even means. Imagine you walk into a supermarket, grab a trolley, leave it somewhere, then walk to the checkout and say "I want to buy everything in this trolley", holding up your empty hands and grinning.

Comment: You're passing arguments to `printf` and `scanf`.  The functions you wrote are no different.

Comment: As mentioned by @paddy, the "forward" definition of the functions indicates what the functions will **receive** as a parameter, not what is _passed-to_ the functions when each is called...

Comment: @paddy That makes sense, I was under the impression that the switch statement would just move to whatever function was needed and that the value would come from the inputHours. I appreciate the feedback!!

Comment: No, function parameters are like new local variables. There is no relationship between the name of a function parameter and the variable (if any) in the caller's scope. You could call `pkgA(someOtherVariable)` or `pkgA(inputHours())` or `pkgA(42)` or `pkgA(hours - 2)`. Whatever value those expressions evaluate to will be then accessible in `pkgA` by the identifier `hours`.

Comment: @jtward17 I think you should start reading a good beginner's C text book.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I am in a online C class but I also attend school full time and work full time so with what little time I do have to complete the stuff for my class I try to ask questions to people on here. The professor I have has responded to none of my messages over the semester.

Comment: @jtward17 reading a book where basic stuff is explained is still a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call each function like this: `pkgA(hours);`

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you! I appreciate the help. If by any chance are there any general formatting issues that you see with my code? Any feedback helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a parameter to your writer function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int inputHours() {
    int hours;
    char hours_verify;

    do {
        do {
            printf("Number of hours from 0 to 720: ");
            scanf(" %i", &hours);
        } while (hours < 0 || hours > 720);

        printf("%i hours, correct?\n", hours);
        printf("Y/N\n");
        scanf(" %c", &hours_verify);

    } while (toupper((unsigned char) hours_verify) != 'Y');

    printf("%i hours of internet were used.\n", hours);

    return (hours);
}

int pkgA(int hours) {
    int pkgprice = 15; //The package price under 50 hours
    int extra_price = 2; //Price per hour over 50 hours

    if (hours <= 50) //Price under 50 hours
    {
        printf("The total price is:$%i", pkgprice);
    } else if (hours <= 720) //Calculate anything over 50 hours
    {
        int extra_hours = hours - 50;

        float total_price = extra_hours * extra_price + pkgprice;
        printf("The total price is:$%.2f", total_price);
    }

    return 0;

}

int pkgB(int hours) {
    int pkgprice = 20; //The package price under 100 hours
    float extra_price = 1.5; //Price per hour over 100 hours

    if (hours <= 100) //Price under 100 hours
    {
        printf("The total price is:%i", pkgprice);
    } else if (100 < hours < 720) //Calculate anything over 100 hours
    {
        int extra_hours = hours - 100;
        printf("%i\n", extra_hours);

        float total_price = extra_hours * extra_price + pkgprice;
        printf("The total price is:$%.2f", total_price);
    }
    return 0;
}

int pkgC(int hours) {
    int pkgprice = 25; //The package price under 150 hours
    int extra_price = 1; //Price per hour over 150 hours

    scanf("%i", &hours);
    printf("%i\n", hours);

    if (hours <= 150) //Price under 150 hours
    {
        printf("The total price is:%i", pkgprice);
    } else if (150 < hours < 720) //Calculate anything over 150 hours
    {
        int extra_hours = hours - 150;
        printf("%i\n", extra_hours);

        float total_price = extra_hours * extra_price + pkgprice;
        printf("The total price is:$%.2f", total_price);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char package_choice;
    char package_verify;

    do {
        printf("Which package would you like to select? A, B, or C ");
        scanf(" %c", &package_choice);

        printf("You chose %c, correct?\n", package_choice);
        printf("Y/N\n");

        scanf(" %c", &package_verify);
    } while (toupper((unsigned char) package_verify) != 'Y');

    printf("You chose package %c.\n", package_choice);

    inputHours;
    int hours = inputHours();

    switch (package_choice) {
        case 'A':
            pkgA(hours);
            break;

        case 'B':
            pkgB(hours);
            break;

        case 'C':
            pkgC(hours);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are defined like this:

```
// pkgA's function prototype
int pkgA(int hours);
^   ^    ^   ^
|   |    |   └- first parameter's name
|   |    └----- first parameter's type (int)
|   └---------- function's name
└-------------- function's return type
```

Your function is expected to return an int.  Callers must pass in an int for hours.  This is what your error is telling you.  Your caller's are not passing in a required value for your function.

```
// function's implementation
int pkgA(int hours)
{
    int i = 9;
    return i + hours;
}
```

You can see here, this implementation takes the in parameter and adds 9 to it, and returns that sum.

```
// another function using pkgA
void f()
{
   int ret = pkgA(9);
   printf("the return value is %i, 18 is expected\n", ret);
}
```

You can see we are passing in values to the function.  We are also capturing the return value.